# sql server combining date_time and smallint columns to derive datetime column in 12 hour format

Tags: sql-server

I have a date_time column and hour_ending column,like below. How do i join them both together to derive a date_time column in 12 hour date format. my requirement is to join Table A with Table B using date_time as join key

**TABLE A**

```
DATE                HOUR_ENDING
---             ----------

8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   1
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   2
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   3
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   4
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   5
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   6
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   7
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   8
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   9
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   10
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   11
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   12
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   13
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   14
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   15
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   16
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   17
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   18
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   19
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   20
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   21
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   22
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   23
8/31/2016 12:00:00.000 AM   24
```

**Table B** (I need Table A to be like this)

```
8/31/2013 12:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 1:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 2:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 3:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 4:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 5:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 6:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 7:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 8:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 9:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 10:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 11:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 12:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 1:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 2:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 3:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 4:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 5:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 6:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 7:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 8:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 9:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 10:00:00 PM
8/31/2013 11:00:00 PM
9/1/2013 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATEADD()` to adjust the dates from the A table using the hour offsets.  Then, join table A to B using this adjusted timestamp.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b
    ON DATEADD(HOUR, a.HOUR_ENDING, a.DATE) = b.DATE
```

By the way you should consider changing your table A design such that date and time are being stored together in a single column.

Comment: Tim, How do I generate a date_time out of just date only column. For instance in the above example what if I have only have date and NOT Hour ending. Is there any way we can sequence the hour ending from 1...24 hours along with the date and generate it in the target format like 8/31/2013 12:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 1:00:00 AM
8/31/2013 2:00:00 AM..... and so forth

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL for this.